# Unique properties of Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, unitarity

Given a general (time-independent) system where I have some Hermitian operator $O$, is there a way of knowing if $O$ happens to be the Hamiltonian?

In other words, are there special mathematical properties that set the Hamiltonian apart from all other Hermitian operators?

(I am looking for a mathematical test, so a physical fact like that its eigenvalues happen to be energies does not count.)

Comment: What is a "time-independent system"? This is not standard terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Question is what is meant by "Hamiltonian", when not working in a context where the physical interpretation is immediate. However, you could ask under which circumstances a given system *could* be given a physical interpretation, and this will lead to two requirements, as far as i can see. Therefore assume $O$ is an operator on a Hilbert space $H$.

1. $O$ should be densely defined, self-adjoint. The reasoning behind this is that $O$ should generate a strongly continuous one-parameter group of unitaries $t \mapsto U(t)$, and Stone's theorem singles out these operators. In physical terms, $U(t)$ is a time evolution of a system generated by $O$. In a physical system, a Hamiltonian is precisely that: the generator of time evolution, therefore an operator that does not generate a time evolution is no sensible Hamiltonian.
2. $O$ should be bounded below. Here the motivation is stability: a physical system should be be stable in the sense that one cannot extract infinitely much energy out of it.

Comment: The request that $O$ should generate a time evolution should be considered as a mathematical or a physical requirement?